# No POST parameters when upload file

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I create an upload file form, but a very strange bug appear ...
When i upload file, symfony don't see POST parameters.

My Form class:

```
class UploadDocumentForm extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->add('name', 'text', array(
      'label' => 'Nom'
    ));
    $builder->add('file', 'file', array(
      'label' => 'Fichier'
    ));
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'upload_document_form';
  }
}
```

My template:

```
<form action="{{ path('upload_file') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {{ form_widget(upload_file_form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer le fichier" />
  </form>
```

My controller action method:

```
public function uploadAction(Request $request)
  {
    $form = $this->createForm(new UploadDocumentForm(), new Document());
    $form->bind($request);
    
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      [...]
    }
    [...]
  }
```

My request (debug with firebug):

```
upload_document_form[name]  blablabla
upload_document_form[file]  ID3����TRCK������03/12TIT2[...]
upload_document_form[_token]    bb5f9925002dafbab[...]
```

My request in symfony debug toolbar:

> Request POST Parameters
>
> No POST parameters

If i make an:

```
die(var_dump($request->get($form->getName())));
```

$request return null.

I've configured php.ini of my /etc/php5/apache/php.ini with:

> file_uploads = On
>
> upload_max_filesize = 100M
>
> max_file_uploads = 28

So, naturally, my form is not valid. The most strange is if i upload a little file (~ under 4Mo), POST data are here, and all work fine !

Comment: What are values for `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`?  Lot more over there -> in "Related" questions...

Comment: Nice connection with related question! post_max_size was to 8M ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ficuscr** comment was correct: I need to configure **post_max_size** to in my php.ini configuration file.

Comment: Was pulling my hair out over this but your answer helped me find a solution.  upload_max_filesize will also cause POST to return nothing if the max file size is exceeded